# Typescript - exporting map of subtypes

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types

I have some classes of the form:

```
abstract class A {}

class AB extends A {}
class AC extends A {}
class AD extends A {}
```

Now in a file I want to export a mapping of class name -> constructors, so something like:

```
export default {
  AB,
  AC,
  AD
};
```

What should be the type of this export?

I tried:

```
type Mappings = {
  [typeName: string]: typeof A
};
```

but when I try something like:

```
import mappings from '..';

let s: string;
const TypeName = mappings[s];
const pr = new TypeName(); // ERROR
```

I get the error: `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class` since A is abstract.

I'm essentially trying to find out how to replace `typeof A` with something like `subtypeof A` or whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `typeof AbstractClass` the type will represent the abstract class itself, meaning it will have an abstract constructor which can't be invoked. The simplest solution is to use a constructor signature instead. The constructor will return an instance of the abstract class but will not be the abstract constructor in the original abstract base class.

```
type Mappings = {
  [typeName: string]: new () => A
};
```